# Cannot open QGIS on my Mac workstation

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

This seems to be a common question for installing QGIS on a Mac and the common solutions have worked in the past for me but now I am stuck.

I have an iMac(27", late 2015) workstation with Mac OS  Monterey (12.7)
I downloaded QGIS 3.32.3-Lima last week and attempted to open it for the first time after installing using the context menu (which has worked previously.) But this time it would not let me set a security exception. I clicked "Open Anyways" and it led to the same message about malicious software.

I have tried rebooting and reinstalling QGIS, booting into safe mode, and launching from the terminal and nothing gets past the malicious software message.

I have talked to our IT department and Apple support and they both had no other ideas.

Is there anything else I can do to get QGIS to launch?